# Ruby Rye, Method Missing error when executing ps -aux shell command

Tags: ruby

I have uby-1.9.3-p551 and rye-v0.9,12 installed

I did the following:

```
rbox = Rye::Box.new("#{@host}")
puts rbox.cat('/tmp/restorelog.txt')
rbox.execute('ps aux | grep ruby > /tmp/ruby-process-list')
```

The cat command functions correctly and lists the input of the file
However, for the execute command I get the following error:

lib/rye/box.rb:462:in `method_missing': ps aux | grep ruby > /tmp/ruby-process-list (Rye::CommandNotFound)

Do I need to add the command first? I assumed the execute method will execute any user defined shell command

Comment: Are you sure that's allowed? [The documentation](https://github.com/delano/rye) implies that pipes are disallowed: "In safe-mode: Pipes and operators don't work: |, &&, >, <, ||, ~, etc…"

Comment: @tadman, I used the example from the online docs http://delanotes.com/rye/

Comment: Hi, checking if somebody has an answer to my question?

Comment: As an additional info: I also tried to run: rbox.execute('ls -al') and also got:  `execute': ls -al (Rye::CommandNotFound). Every shell command I try to use throws the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before using the execute method, you must disable safe_mode:

```
rbox.disable_safe_mode
```

Then, your code will look like:

```
rbox = Rye::Box.new("#{@host}")
puts rbox.cat('/tmp/restorelog.txt')
rbox.disable_safe_mode
rbox.execute('ps aux | grep ruby > /tmp/ruby-process-list')
```

As stated in the documentation:

> When safe-mode is disabled, you can run any command (regardless of what is defined in the whitelist) with any valid arguments (fileglobs, tildas, etc...).

The "etc" part include pipes.